# How does one set the default Eclipselink CacheCoordinateType in the persistence.xml?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

if you look at this page:
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_cache.htm

It says the following:

> (Optional) Set this attribute to the cache coordination mode (org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.CacheCoordinationType enumerated type). You must also configure cache coordination in your persistence unit properties. See "Caching".

I cannot for the life of me figure what property to set, as the referenced docs do not provide an example. I tried this but got an exception:

`<property
    name="eclipselink.cache.type.coordinationType"
    value="INVALIDATE_CHANGED_OBJECTS" />`

```
Sep 10 22:57:15 apps-3 run.sh[24742]:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property eclipselink.cache.type.coordinationType has an illegal value INVALIDATE_CHANGED_OBJECTS.
Sep 10 22:57:15 apps-3 run.sh[24742]: #011at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.PropertiesHandler$Prop.getValueToApply(PropertiesHandler.java:366)
Sep 10 22:57:15 apps-3 run.sh[24742]: #011at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.PropertiesHandler$Prop.getPrefixValuesToApply(PropertiesHandler.java:322)
Sep 10 22:57:15 apps-3 run.sh[24742]: #011at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.PropertiesHandler.getPrefixValuesLogDebug(PropertiesHandler.java:155)
Sep 10 22:57:15 apps-3 run.sh[24742]: #011at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.updateDescriptorCacheSettings(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1424)
Sep 10 22:57:15 apps-3 run.sh[24742]: #011at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.updateSession(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2729)
Sep 10 22:57:15 apps-3 run.sh[24742]: #011at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:713)
Sep 10 22:57:15 apps-3 run.sh[24742]: #011at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:207)
Sep 10 22:57:15 apps-3 run.sh[24742]: #011at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:307)
Sep 10 22:57:15 apps-3 run.sh[24742]: #011at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)
Sep 10 22:57:15 apps-3 run.sh[24742]: #011at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:318)
Sep 10 22:57:15 apps-3 run.sh[24742]: #011at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:208)
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured I'd add an answer for anyone else looking:

We add the following PU properties and caching works pretty well! We're running on Apache TomEE, so the `openejb:Resource/jms/connectionFactory` value below will vary if you're on another app server

```
        <property
            name="eclipselink.cache.coordination.protocol"
            value="jms" />
        <property
            name="eclipselink.cache.coordination.jms.topic"
            value="openejb:Resource/com.xxx.applications.eclipselink.cache" />
        <property
            name="eclipselink.cache.coordination.jms.factory"
            value="openejb:Resource/jms/connectionFactory" />
        <property
            name="eclipselink.cache.coordination.jms.reuse-topic-publisher"
            value="true" />
        <property
            name="eclipselink.cache.coordination.remove-connection-on-error"
            value="true" />
        <property
            name="eclipselink.session.name"
            value="com.xxx.xxx-jpa-model" />
```